# bootstrap's container-fluid's class is not working in django

Tags: python, html, css, django, bootstrap-4

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
   <img class="graph" src="{% static 'images/graph.png' %}"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hi. I need to resize the **graph.png** static image to full width of the screen. But it leaves a blank white space to the left and right margins of the screen. I have used the following CSS for it. The image is resizing to the width of the screen if used in a raw HTML but not in Django. In short, the **container-fluid** is not doing its job. But other bootstrap classes like grid, buttons and other classes are working very perfectly.

```
.graph{
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: can you create a demo to reproduce your issue so we can have a look

Comment: open dev console to inspect and to see styles applied to element.

Answer (score 0):

Try without define height

```
.graph{
padding: 0;
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
max-width: 100%;}
```